# Open folder in VS Code tab instead of new window

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, tabs

I'm fairly new to Mac OSX and as a developer, I'm using VS Code heavily. I noticed it has support for tabs, so that I can open different folders in different tabs. However, each time I open a folder in VS Code from the command-line, it opens in a new window. I then have to go to the "Window" menu and select "Merge All Windows". Is it possible to tell either Mac OSX or VS Code to always open the folder in a tab of the existing VS Code window?

Comment: Finder has a pref for prefer tabs, but I'd assume VS Code would have its own pref [I don't use it so don't know where it might be hiding]

Comment: So I guess it's app specific?